# How can I validate Stripe publishable_key?

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there any way to validate Stripe `publishable_key` key?

Currently, there is only one way I found to do this, that is to **call a Payment Intent and see if it responds to any errors**.

But is this method good?

Because I'm creating a **useless Intent**, I don't know if this is good or bad.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What's your use case? Why would you need to validate the key?

Comment: I'm building e-commerce, user can add Stripe payment by simply providing their `publishable_key ` and `secret_key`

Comment: Sharing of API keys isn't recommended by Stripe as it poses a security risk. Also Stripe can change the format of API keys at any point with no notice. Instead you should look into using Stripe Connect instead, which lets you do what you want without having to share API keys: https://stripe.com/docs/connect